# Por que al crear una lista devuelve None python

Tags: python, lista, lambda

```
> def velas(data):

    return list(
        map(
            lambda v: {
                "open_time": float(v[0]),
                "open": float(v[1]),
                "high": float(v[2]),
                "low": float(v[3]),
                "close": float(v[4]),
            },
            data,
        )
    )
```

Cuando creo esta funcion, tendria que arrojarme un listado ordenado de valores, pero la salida es "None"

Comment: No parece haber un error en el código publicado. Podrías poner un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) por favor?

Comment: ¿Qué es `data`?

Comment: @ChemaCortes es que, no importa el valor de data, es casi imposible que la función publicada devuelva None. Lo más cercano debería ser una lista vacía. Si data fuera None, posiblemente devolvería el error "NoneType object is not iterable"

Comment: Era por saber algo más de cómo se llama a esta función (aunque no entiendo qué es el signo `>` al principio). Tal como está, solo se puede decir que es imposible que devuelva `None`. Se necesita más contexto, algún caso de ejemplo para probarla y el modo en que es llamada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos pasos:

1. Crear la función usando `def`.
2. Llamarla con `velas(...)`.

   ```
    def velas(data):    
        return list(
            map(
                lambda v: {
                    "open_time": float(v[0]),
                    "open": float(v[1]),
                    "high": float(v[2]),
                    "low": float(v[3]),
                    "close": float(v[4]),
                },
                data,
            )
        )

    print(velas([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]]))
   ```

   produce

   ```
    [{'open_time': 1.0, 'open': 2.0, 'high': 3.0, 'low': 4.0, 'close': 5.0}, {'open_time': 10.0, 'open': 20.0, 'high': 30.0, 'low': 40.0, 'close': 50.0}]

    Process finished with exit code 0
   ```

Comment: Perdón si no capté algo, pero... cual sería el objetivo de esta respuesta?